# How to calculate RC values according to threshold points of a Schmitt trigger inverting oscillator [updated]

Tags: oscillator, logic-gates, schmitt-trigger

I'm trying to make a high-period, low duty cycle signal to trigger a regulator (EN pin) for lower power consumption. I tried to simulate this simple circuit in various simulation software, using "schmitt-trigger inverter" or 74HC14 as the inverter and it was OK. The results were quite similar; A period of few seconds and a duty cycle of 10%. ([simulation link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAnEbQvcFPjz5hiKKN1xxOtMIX58as8KPHZJUgMbKxKBHJFjsacTHhwIYaDUyRZKURhS7sGOadtsAJiBQ0qhGm5IQICfEE8GADMAQwBXABsAFy8gwNYdP3AwHXCouKS2AHdtHz0Sp0DIIu5eeRrhbKhq3DTGoSyxKuKWkFDFOVCumQHA-rqh3380lUHqyY6S9Kbig17psSWh1aXViqaAcxKjKlXsBE6msDx6Xd96nzuqGCQYPkNoeiH209q9obHVmM-s1fncgY82O1waM8FQ-k0APbgJCDWiQUjUdyQbDESCEXTiDZIbBsIA))

[image: simulation of Schmitt-trigger, inverter oscillator]

However, in a real test, I used a [74LVC1G04](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9v-zh8fX0AhUJ8rsIHTNVDpQQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.nexperia.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata-sheet%2F74LVC1G04.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0fIllcL0oJNawGmdL0Ua_G) single schmitt-trigger inverter and the results were quite unexpected. The duty cycle was nearly exact (1/10 as the 33K and 330K resistors suggest) but the period was very low. something about hundreds of milliseconds while I got 5~7 seconds in simulations. When I used a big 220uF I could get results near the expected ~7 seconds. I thought the problem should be something about thresholds of schmitt-trigger. when I use the values provided by datasheet in simulation, I still get somehow the same simulation results, quite far from the real millisecond periods. here are the values I chose for simulation parameter values :

[image: threshold values for schmitt-trigger]

The real circuit uses [1N4148](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwilpsuE9PX0AhXVhP0HHTXCCAsQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vishay.com%2Fdocs%2F81857%2F1n4148.pdf&usg=AOvVaw22CFdBP8h4zMOjVcavnmjh) diodes and a 0603 X5R 16V capacitor. power supply is regulated 3.3V. I measured the TP which was connected to EN pin. I don't think the EN pin (which is not pulled to anywhere according to datasheet) has to do anything with this. no other component is connected to the TP-EN point.
What could be the problem?

---

### UPDATE:

A picture of the real test values. 180ms period and 8ms high cycle:

- 4.7uF cap
- 330K resistance changed to 1M
- 33K is actually 39K (I didn't have 33K available)
- I cut off the output to the regulator EN pin. it seems it has no effect on it.

[image: the real test]

And a picture of the tiny PCB itself. the connection to regulator is cut off. they just share a GND. nothing else.

[image]

*thanx for the time and knowledge.*

Comment: https://2n3904blog.com/cd40106-schmitt-trigger-relaxation-oscillator/

Comment: What power supply rails is your falsestad circuit operating at. Schmitt trigger thresholds widen with a bigger supply voltage and there's no way of telling with that marvellous bit of software from the picture you posted.

Comment: @G36 that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Andyaka it's 5V in the simulation but 3.3V in real tests.

Comment: And what threshold are schmitt used?

Comment: @Andyaka 0.8v for lower threshold and 2v for top threshold.

Comment: I am talking about the fallstad simulation in case you were just repeating what the data sheet says.

Comment: Did you take into account the leakage current of the devices (input current inverter and capacitor) ?

Comment: @Andyaka yes I meant the values I entered into "editcomponent" window of falstad schmitt trigger. they are 0.8v for lower part and 2.0v  for upper. the various simulations are ok. the real test differs significantly with them.

Comment: @Antonio51 nope. not at all. but can they affect it to change a 7s simulated period to under 1s?

Comment: The input leakage of inverter, maybe not be important. The leakage of the capacitor to verify. I tried with a resistor of 1 Meg in parallel with C, period changes significantly.

Comment: Are both diodes pointing the same way (they shouldn't be of course).

Comment: 1Meg as leakage of capacitor change period by a factor of 3 (tested on CD4093B). Current leakage is 0.01*C*V.  (C in uf, current in uA), for 100uF, 3uA -> 1Meg leakage.

Comment: @Andyaka nah they are fine. I just brushed the board with flux cleaner and it cleared their marking. but they are in right direction. double checked it.

Comment: For tantale capacitor, leakage from 3uA to 40 uA.